# Proof of Bolzano-Weierstrass: how are we inductively choosing a strictly increasing sequence as below?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand the proof that every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. The proof goes as follows:

> Let $\{a_{n}\}$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers. Choose $M\ge 0$
> such that $|a_{n}|\le M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Define sets
> $$E_{n}=\overline{\{a_{j} \mid j\ge n}\}.$$ Then, $E_{n}\subseteq [-M, M]$ are a descending sequence of non-empty, closed and bounded subsets
> of $\mathbb{R}$. The nested interval theorem then says that there
> exists some $a$ such that $$a \in \bigcap_{n\ge 1}E_{n}.$$ For each
> natural number $k$, $a$ is a point of closure of $\{a_{j}\mid j\ge k\}$. Hence, for infinitely many indices $j\ge n$ (shouldn't it be $j\ge k$?), $$a_{j}\in (a-\frac{1}{k}, a+\frac{1}{k}).$$ We may
> therefore inductively choose a strictly increasing sequence of natural
> numbers $\{n_{k}\}$ such that $|a-a_{n_{k}}|<1/k$ for all $k$.

My question is how exactly are the points in the sequence being chosen such that they're guaranteed to be strictly increasing? I'm not able to visualize how this process works.

Can you can please explain how starting with $k=1$ we inductively construct the subsequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point $a$ is in $\bigcap_n E_n$, which means it is in every $E_n$. The set $E_n$ is the result of throwing away the first $n - 1$ (I'm assuming here $\Bbb{N}$ begins at $1$) terms of the sequence, and taking the closure. So, $a$ is a point that is in the closure of the sequence values, no matter how many we throw away.

So, if we put a little interval $\left(a - \frac{1}{k}, a + \frac{1}{k}\right)$ around $a$, there must always be points from the sequence lying in this interval, (once again) no matter how many terms we throw away.

Let's take $k = 1$ to start. Then, we are looking at the interval $(a - 1, a + 1)$, which must contain some sequence term (after all, $a \in E_1$, which is the closure of all the sequence terms). Pick one, any one, and call the index of the sequence $n_1$.

Next, the interval $\left(a - \frac{1}{2}, a + \frac{1}{2}\right)$ must contain sequence terms, no matter how many we throw away. Let us throw the first $n_1$ terms of the sequence. So, we are considering $E_{n_1 + 1}$. Since $a \in E_{n_1 + 1}$, there must be some $m > n_1$ such that $a_m \in \left(a - \frac{1}{2}, a + \frac{1}{2}\right)$. We'll let $n_2 = m$. Note, by construction $n_2 > n_1$.

Next, with $\left(a - \frac{1}{3}, a + \frac{1}{3}\right)$, we use the fact that $a \in E_{n_2 + 1}$, and use this to obtain an $n_3 > n_2$, such that $a_{n_3} \in \left(a - \frac{1}{3}, a + \frac{1}{3}\right)$, and so on, and so on. The constructed sequence of natural numbers increases strictly, and by construction $|a - a_{n_k}| < \frac{1}{k}$, as needed.

Hope that helps. Let me know if you have follow-up questions.

Comment: Thank you so much, this clears everything up.

Answer (score 0):

For $\;k=1\;$ :

$$E_1=\overline{\{a_j\;|\; j\ge1\}}$$

For $\;k=2\;$

$$E_2=\overline{\{a_j\;|\; j\ge2\}}\subset E_1$$

and etc.